# bootstrap datetimepicker localization

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Localization calendar is not coming from my snippet

```
$("#txtServiceFromDate").data("DateTimePicker").function({
        locale:'fr'
    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#txtServiceToDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
    });

 $("#txtServiceFromDate").datetimepicker({
        pickTime: false,

    }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#txtServiceToDate').data("DateTimePicker").setMinDate(e.date);
    });
```

Comment: have you added the fr localization file into your page?

Comment: yes i have added 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.fr.min.js
in my script

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong localisation file from a different library, you need the localisation file for [moment.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moment/moment/develop/locale/fr.js) from what i can see from the [documentation](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#locale)

You also need to initiate the language when you initiate the plugin

```
 $('#txtServiceFromDate').datetimepicker({
    locale:'fr'
});
```

or:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").locale('fr')
```

in version lower 4.0.0 you do

```
$('#txtServiceFromDate').datetimepicker({ language :'fr' });
```

Comment: yes,tried this before your answer and after your ans, i tried once again.

Comment: and ? did you get any errors? have you tried `$('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").locale('fr')` instead of `$("#txtServiceFromDate").data("DateTimePicker").function({
        locale:'fr'
    })`

Comment: one more note is that my application have bootstrap datetimepicker v3.1.3

Comment: for v3.1.3 the attribute for locale is `language` so you do `$('#txtServiceFromDate').datetimepicker({
    language :'fr'
});`

Comment: i have tried this solution but its also not working.

Comment: can you tell me what plugin you are using for fr locale? please suggest what cdn link ll be used for language:'fr'

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/locale/fr.js ,this should work